# If a wff is longer then the sum occurrences of atoms and connectives is bigger.

Tags: logic, induction, propositional-calculus

Let $\#(\phi)$ denote the sum of (not necessarily distinct) occurrences of atoms and connectives of the wff $\phi$.
Let $l(\phi)$ denote length of the wff $\phi$.

Is it true that for all wff's $\phi$ and $\psi$ $l(\phi)\ge l(\psi)\implies \#(\phi) \ge \#(\psi)$ ,[with equality on the left hand side implying equality on the right hand side] ?

I think that this is indeed true, but have been unable to prove it,it should be noted though that in order for this to be true, the sum is needed, if one takes $\#$ to instead be occurances of atoms or occurrences of connectives then its false.[One can easily construct counterexamples]

Comment: "the sum of (not necessarily distinct) occurrences of " what do you mean? In $\lnot \lnot p$ we have two occurrences of the "$\lnot$" symbol, obviously distinct.

Comment: Thus, IMO, in $\lnot \lnot p$ we have **two** symbols but **three** occurrences of symbols.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Correct  the # value is 3 ! But you should put brackets to make it a wff

Comment: Please include some more information on exactly what connectives are allowed (maybe $\lnot, \lor, \land$?) and some examples showing what convention you're using for parentheses and what $l(\varphi)$ and $|\varphi|$ are in a few concrete cases such as $(A \land (\lnot B))$ and $(A \land (\lnot A))$. Also, please include an induction argument that you started; that will help us give more useful answers.

Comment: The only way to prove this is with an induction argument, and the argument is completely typical, so someone looking for induction-related examples in the future may be interested to find this one.

Comment: The definition of a wff might matter here.  If we use a parentheses free prefix notation, NNNNx having length 5 is shorter than KKKabcd having length 7.  But, if we use parentheses, we have N(N(N(N(x)))) has length 13, while K(K(K(a,b),c),d) has length 13 if we don't count the ',' symbols.  If we do count, the ',' symbols, it has length 16, but difference between the lengths still differs, and thus it seems likely that formula "A" having less length than "B" in wff system Q might not hold for wff system R also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, ***this is false***, consider the wffs $\large (\neg(\neg(\neg(\neg(\neg b)))))$ and $\large (((b\land b)\land b)\land b)$ where $\large b$ is an atom.

*Clearly the first is longer than the second, $\#$ for the first one is 6 and for the second one it is 7.*

At least if I counted correctly!

Comment: Typically the syntax of WFFs doesn't put parentheses around $\lnot b$.

Comment: @MJD *It does not matter*, its even easier to come up with counterexamples in that case. Also r.e. it being "typical", it should be noted that two of the most popular logic books , enderton and van dalen, use parentheses around $(\neg b)$, so I am not so sure if that claim is really warranted. Also I noticed you say in the comments to the question that this is a typical excercise in induction, as I show in my answer that's not correct [I am reposting this as one complete comment, to avoid clutter]